# Attribute error module 'django.db.models' has no attribute RichTextUploadingField

Tags: python, django, ckeditor4.x

Hi am trying to integrate ckeditor in my blog and here is the error am getting help out 
when i try to use from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField,RichTextField,
error cannot import RichTextField
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.conf import settings
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=(
        ('Published','Published'),
        ('Draft','Draft'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.RichTextUploadingField()
    Category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seo_title = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True,null=True)
    seo_description = models.CharField(max_length=125,blank=True,null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='Draft',choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    thumb=models.ImageField(blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug=slugify(self.title)
        super(Post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:300]+'....'
    #def get_absolute_url(self):
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pages',
    'blog',
    'django_social_share',
    'taggit',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]






STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
#PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')


#...
SITE_ID = 1

####################################
    ##  CKEDITOR CONFIGURATION ##
####################################

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None,
    },
}
```

also trying to use the import from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField says cannot import from  RichTextField

Comment: Here's the error: `body = models.RichTextUploadingField()`. Change this to `body = RichTextUploadingField()`.

Comment: thanks worked! more explanations please, and why trying to import both like from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextField, RichTextUploadingField   Give an error cannot import RichTextField

Comment: `RichTextUploadingField` is in `ckeditor_uploader.fields` whereas `RichTextField` is in `ckeditor.fields`. They are in separate files. So you have to import them from separate locations. You can't do that in a single import statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using:  `models.RichTextUploadingField()` that is not actually an model module Class, you are importing it from another library, so you should use just `body = RichTextUploadingField()`.

Comment: Can i know the reason behind more explanations please